# PHP attempts to run require_once even though it shouldn't

Tags: php

I am having the strangest time with the following PHP code. The require_once runs in the else statement even though the if statement is true. What is also strange is that $controller in the else statement recieves the value of "application." There is no other code related to the following other than $total's value.

```
    $total = $uri->total();

    if($total == 0) {

        //Home Page Controller
        $controller = 'index';
        $method = false;

    } else {

        $controller = $uri->segment(1); //value is "account"

        if($uri->segment(2) !== false) {
            $method = $uri->segment(2); //value is "login"
        } else {
            $method = false;
        }
    }

    require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$controller.EXT);

    $$controller = new $controller;

    if($method != false) {
        $$controller->$method();
    } else {
        $$controller->index();
    }
```

Edit: I fixed the double-code so that the same code is not called twice in either the if or the else. When I run this, the code works, but I get an error on the line where the require_once is: cannot find application.php

This is strange because require_once is already loading the correct class, but I am getting an error that it cannot find the right file. What would cause it to load twice? I've checked to make sure the file this PHP is in doesn't load twice.

This is all the code I am working with except the URI class found here: https://github.com/chrisabrams/PHP-URI-Class

I am not sure where application.php comes from.

Comment: what happens if you `var_dump($total);` as the first line after the else {

Comment: You have some code smell... You have duplicate code in the `if` and in the `else`. The code from `$$controller = new $controller;` should be outside (at the end) the `if` statement

Comment: In fact, the `if` should define  `$controller` and `$method`

Comment: AIIEIIEEEEE variable variables... the goggles... they do nothing!

Comment: The edit to the code invalidates the original description, so this question no longer makes sense.

Comment: I've tried to close the question but it hasn't gotten enough votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved: http://codeigniter.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have the same require_once statement in both the 'if' and 'else' blocks.

Comment: the value of $controller differs

Comment: This answer is way too wrong, unless $uri->segment(1) == 'index' (:

Comment: Ha - whoops. I should read more carefully...

Comment: Just edit your answer to correct one.